# Is it possible to compare my received msg with resource in xml or textview and edittext

Tags: android

I can start another activity when i receive a sms. what I want to know is **how to compare the text message with the content in my resources(xml string) and also the textview, editText**. **Is it possible to get reference from textview and edittext value in broadcast receiver class?** Below is the code starting an activity without comparing any value.

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{       
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";     
    String phonenumber = "";

    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            phonenumber=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress(); 
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";        
        }

        //=======launch the ShowMap1 when recieve SMS==============//
        Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(context, ShowMap2.class);
        mainActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        mainActivityIntent.putExtra("phn", phonenumber);
        mainActivityIntent.putExtra("sms", str);

        context.startActivity(mainActivityIntent);  
        //========================END=============================//  

    }                         
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understood that will be a global receiver that will get SMS.

So it means that the device can be on sleep, on the home screen, on the some game, on the gmail, or any other app; so that means that the Activity and the EditText do not exist at the moment that this receiver is being fired.

You can save a previously entered value from the activity on the SharedPreferences for example, and compare from those values.

To compare from an XML resource is very simple, you're receiving a reference to your application context with this receiver, just use it to get the value with this code:

```
String compare = context.getString(R.string.___);
```

Comment: `context.getString` is even better solution

Comment: it's the same at the end. But sure, the code looks smaller. I typed it by heart.

Comment: Also `getResources` is a method. You are missing the calling brackets. I would strive to improve my answers if i were you.

Comment: edited. I type stuff by heart, those stuff is bound to happen.

Comment: 10x for d effort!!! vy much appreciate!! I was try to get reference to my sharepreferences n i manage to do it! tknx and sry cause i cant vote for u since my reputation is below 15 :(